# text box item not removed

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a 1) Text filed
2) Drop down list
3)List Box

Im write  code for Drop down list selected value add the the list box and text filed , i can remove the list box value but cant remove the text filed value, please how to write code remove the same adding value for text filed and list box

[image]
[image]

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQlt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="348px" OnTextChanged="txtQlt_TextChanged" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>


                                        </div><div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:115px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>   
                                    </div>

                                    <br />
                                       <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">

                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Quality reference"  Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID ="cmbQualityRef" runat ="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="250px" >

                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:ListBox  ID="lstValue" runat="server" CssClass="content" Rows="5" ValidationGroup="save"
                                            Width="250"  ></asp:ListBox>

                                        </div>
                                    <asp:ImageButton  ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="add"
                                            OnClick="btnAdd_Click"  ImageUrl="~/img/Add.png"/>

                                           <asp:ImageButton   ID="btnImageRemove" runat="server" OnClick="btnImageRemove_Click"
                                                         ImageUrl="~/img/Remove.png" /> 

                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:16px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>   
                                    </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void btnImageRemove_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (lstValue.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem);
                }
                //lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem.Text);


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
        }
```

---

```
private void AddToList()
{





    if (lstValue.Items.Count > 0)
    {

        txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text + "," + cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        txtQlt.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }


    ListItem itm = new ListItem();
    itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
    itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();

    lstValue.Items.Add(itm);
    lstValue.Items.Remove("");

}
```

---

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AddToList();






                    lstValue.Items.Remove("");





        }
```

Comment: 1. Can you reconstruct your sentence and ask the question with specific definitions? 
 2. To answer your question:

You succesfully removed the DropDownList item when you click the ImageButton. Simply use `txtQlt.Text = String.Empty;` to clear the content of your TextBox. Use this line of code inside the `if` block where you defined the remove event. You can paste it after `lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem);` IF you were asking something else, please state it clearly with a complete sentence.

Comment: i want to remove the two item in one button click, please like this uploaded image

Comment: where you do the remove on button click, set the textbox to empty also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question as I understand it, when you are removing the selected item, also set the textbox to empty.

```
 if (lstValue.SelectedItem != null)
   {
      lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem);
      txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text.Replace(lstValue.SelectedItem.ToString(), "");

   }
```

Comment: Sir @harry, Im change your code  now its working ,Thanks for the help
 `txtQlt= String.Empty;` , but i have one problem. im select the one list box item and after remove it, actually  remove all of values for the text filed

Comment: sir @harry but i have one problem. im select the one list box item and after remove it, actually remove all of values for the text filed

Comment: I see, so you only want to remove substring from the text field?

Comment: i want to remove , list box and text filed values

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't make sense. That is what the code is doing, removing the listbox item and setting text field to empty? am I missing something? please can you clarify...

Comment: sir, actually i want to remove selected list box value and text filed values, your answer 99% best answer, its have a little problem , its remove the  all of text filed value not a selected value,i think use full for `loop` method

Comment: im try this, but not working , its working only selected list box value, but same text filed value not remove, example, List Box Value AA, Text Filed Value AA not remove, only remove AA(List Box Value)

Comment: to remove you just set textbox.Text = String.Empty; I am sorry but I don't seem to understand quite what you are after...

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, Im try to this

Comment: please do let me know if you get somewhere with it, I would be interested to see what we were missing

Comment: sir @harry its working i make some change ` if (lstValue.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text.Replace(lstValue.SelectedItem.ToString(), "").Trim();
                lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem);
            }`  should remove item from list after replacing the string,other wise it can't find the item from list.

Comment: your are help me ,  my respect for you

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working

```
if (lstValue.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text.Replace(lstValue.SelectedItem.ToString(), "").Trim();
                lstValue.Items.Remove(lstValue.SelectedItem);
            }
```